# Select box populated dynamically with AJAX doesn't post on form submission

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

This is my first attempt at chaining select boxes in a web form using ajax and I I'm obviously missing something.  I'm simply at a loss for what that is, exactly.  Here is my issue:

A user selects a Country from one select box and an ajax request is made and options (containing names of States and Territories) are returned to a select box below.  **While the options are returned into the form select field, the user-selected option is NOT sent when the form is submitted.**

Here is the code I've cooked up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("select#state").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("select#country").change(function(){
        $("select#state").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#state").html("<option>Loading States...</option>");
        var id = $("select#country option:selected").attr('value');
          $.post("http://example.com/terms.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#state").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#state").html(data);
          });
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see the live example here (see the Country/State section):

http://shredtopia.com/add/

Any ideas what is needed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

As far i can see, the user input is sent

```
input_32    79
input_29    alberta
```

Being 79 the country *canada* and *alberta* the state.

```
<select tabindex="11" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_1_32" name="input_32"></select>
<select tabindex="12" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_1_29" name="input_29" disabled=""></select>
```

Maybe i misunderstood the issue?

Comment: The form doesn't submit the State `#input_1_29`.  It submits the country `#input_1_32` (which is NOT populated with AJAX), but not the States.

Comment: Check the **name** of the selects, the **name** is **input_32** and **input_29**, not **input_1_29** and **input_1_32**, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Not it, the field ID's are used, not the name.

Comment: When you send a form, the names are used as the keys, as you can check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**Try .live( eventType,handler )**

**Description**: Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Add to your code and try it~

```
$('select#state').live('change', function() {
   var id = $("select#state option:selected").attr('value');
   alert(id);
});
```

---

**Or try this:**

add a hidden in form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue">
```

alter your select#state like this:

```
<select onchange='innerValue(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)'></select>
```

and create a javascript function

```
function innerValue(value){
        $("#hiddenValue").val(value)
     }
```

then,click submitbutton,`$("#hiddenValue").val()` is you need

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
            alert($("#hiddenValue").val())
        })
```

but,I think this is not the best solution...

Comment: Alter word: "country" => "state"